# What is the name of these colorful connectors?

Tags: connector, identification, speakers

What is the name of these colorful connector? Standard one or priority? One of the molex family? What is the exact name?

PS: The connector is used to attach speakers. There is a marking on each one that 'says' KL.

Anyone?

---

[image: connector image]

Comment: You sure about those dimensions? Seems kind of big..

Comment: They have just shrunk :)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You are right, changed it

Comment: Who uses decimillimeters nowedays?

Comment: There are identification marks on the side of them that you haven't mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Transistor Added to the question, 'KL' is on each connector.

Comment: @Huisman, there is such a thing as decimeter, but i do not think that there is a decimillimeter ..... it would be micrometer instead

Comment: @jsotola Check [en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) or other google hits

Comment: @Huisman, like i said .... `Prefixes may not be used in combination.`

Comment: @jsotola Hence: Who uses decimillimeters *nowedays*?

Comment: Still no answer.....